# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Group": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite

**Error**

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Group": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table Group(_id integer primary key autoincrement, GroupName TEXT , MemberName TEXT , TotalExpense TEXT );
```

**Code:-**

```
public static final String CREATE_GROUP_TABLE = "create table " + ROOM_GROUP_TABLE +
            "(" + GROUP_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + ROOM_COLUMN_GROUP_NAME + " TEXT , "
            + ROOM_COLUMN_MEMBER_NAME + " TEXT , "
            + ROOM_COLUMN_TOTAL_EXPENSE + " TEXT );";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your table name can't be Group, Group is a keyword.

List of sqlite keywords: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html